# How do I check if a list is sorted in Haskell using list comprehension?

Tags: sorting, haskell, computer-science

I'm trying to check if a list is sorted either ascending or descending in Haskell. I understand list comprehension the best in Haskell right now.

Currently, I have...

```
ascending l = [ x > (head(tail l))| x <- l]
```

and

```
descending l = [ x < (head (tail l))| x <- l]
```

but it's only comparing the each item in them list against one value and returning true and false whether it's greater or less than and that's not what I'm looking for. I want it to tell me if a list is true whether it's increasing or decreasing.

Comment: List comprehension is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: I tend to agree with n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. that this is better solved with direct recursion than with comprehensions, but actually it _can_ be done quite nicely with a list comprehension over [`tails`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails).

Answer (score 2):

Whether a list is sorted is a `Bool`, and list comprehensions always return lists, so it's impossible with nothing outside of the list comprehension, but you can do it with one function outside, like this:

```
ascending l = and [x <= y | (x, y) <- zip l (tail l)]
descending l = and [x >= y | (x, y) <- zip l (tail l)]
```

Or like this:

```
import Data.List
ascending l = and [x <= y | x:y:_ <- tails l]
descending l = and [x >= y | x:y:_ <- tails l]
```

But as n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. said in a comment, this really isn't the right tool for the job, so you shouldn't actually do this this way in production.

Comment: they seem to want one function that returns true, whether the list is ascending or descending.